# Finding special modules

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Given a representation-finite algebra $A$. Is there a quick method to find all modules $M$ with $End_A(M)=A$? Motivation is that those are the modules with a natural $A$-bimodule structure. We might additionally assume that A is a quiver algebra with n simples. Is there something better than doing the following:

1. Find the set X of all indecomposable modules.
2. Build all n-subsets of X.
3. Compute all endomorphism rings of n-subets and check if you get A.

For example one might think that M has to have certain modules as summands or certain modules cant appear as summands. Maybe there is even another much quicker method. Maybe there is a good necessary condition to exclude alot of modules M with n summands?